mongo atlas model is present but the documents are not getting created
i have started using next js lately and i'm new backend technologies , i have established the connection with monogdb atlas using moongose which works as expected but the post request date which is user obj which is getting sent but not created as document in collection , but the collection is getting created in the post request
//signup route.ts

import {connect} from '@/dbConfig/dbConfig';
import User from '@/models/userModal.js';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse} from 'next/server';


connect()

export async function POST(request:NextRequest){
    try {
        const reqBody =  await request.json()
        const {username, email, password} = reqBody;
        console.log(reqBody)

        //check if user already exists

         const user = await User.findOne({email})
         if(user){
            return NextResponse.json({error:"user already exists"},
            {status:400})
         }

         //hash password
         const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
         const hashsedPassword = await bcrypt.hash
         (password,salt)

         const newUser = new user({
            username,
            email,
            password:hashsedPassword
        })

        const savedUser = await newUser.save()
        console.log(savedUser);
        
        return NextResponse.json({
            message:"user created succesfully", 
            success:true,
            savedUser
        },
        {status:201})

        
    } catch (error:any) {
        return NextResponse.json({error:error.message},
            {status:500})
        
    }
}




//dbConfig.ts

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export async function connect() {
    try {
        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!);
        const connection = mongoose.connection;

        connection.on('connected', () => {
            console.log('MongoDB connected successfully');
        })

        connection.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. ' + err);
            process.exit();
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Something goes wrong!');
        console.log(error);
        
    }


}


In the post req the new instance of User has to refer to the User but I referred to the user syntactical error.
//signup route.ts

import {connect} from '@/dbConfig/dbConfig';
import User from '@/models/userModal.js';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse} from 'next/server';


connect()

export async function POST(request:NextRequest){
    try {
        const reqBody =  await request.json()
        const {username, email, password} = reqBody;
        console.log(reqBody)

        //check if user already exists

         const user = await User.findOne({email})
         if(user){
            return NextResponse.json({error:"user already exists"},
            {status:400})
         }

         //hash password
         const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
         const hashsedPassword = await bcrypt.hash
         (password,salt)

/* new user was wrong reference to the User 
which is the modal constructor */
         const newUser = new User({ 
            username,
            email,
            password:hashsedPassword
        })

        const savedUser = await newUser.save()
        console.log(savedUser);
        
        return NextResponse.json({
            message:"user created succesfully", 
            success:true,
            savedUser
        },
        {status:201})

        
    } catch (error:any) {
        return NextResponse.json({error:error.message},
            {status:500})
        
    }
}

